# Как в AngularJS организовать постояную передачу данных через фабрику?

Tags: angularjs

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.factory('Storage', function() {
  var _from = '';
  return {
    setFrom: function(from) {
      _from = from;
    },
    getFrom: function() {
      return _from;
    }

  }
})

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Storage',
  function($scope, Storage) {
    $scope.test = "";
    $scope.testClick1 = function() {
      var tStorage = Storage;
      tStorage.setFrom($scope.test);
      console.log("set", $scope.test);
    };
  }
])

.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Storage',
  function($scope, Storage) {
    $scope.testClick2 = function() {
      $scope.test = Storage.getFrom();
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
    {{test}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="test">
    <button ng-click="testClick1()">sad</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="View2Ctrl">
    {{ tests}}
    <button ng-click="testClick2()">sad</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Есть фабрика (Storage), через которую хочу передавать некоторые данные веденые пользователем ($scope.test)
 из контроллера (View1Ctrl) в контроллер (View2Ctrl).

Так как это вводимые пользователем данные, то на момент создания контроллера их еще нет и данные передаются при активации сначала функции $scope.testClick1, а потом $scope.testClick2 - только после этого получаем в втором контроллере (View2Ctrl) необходимые нам данные.

Как это можно организовать (автоматизировать), подразумевается что кнопочки отправить (активирующие $scope.testClick1 быть не должно)?

Comment: так какое все-таки ожидаемое поведение должно быть?